# Alineación de div y botón con bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Hola estoy tratando de colocar el boton **cancelar venta** en la misma altura que esta el boton **confirmar venta**

Estoy tratando pero sin resultado espero me entiendan

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

 <section class="content">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="box box-solid box-primary">
                                <div class="box-header">
                                    <h3 class="box-title">
                                        <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Venta
                                    </h3>
                                </div>
                                <!--<br>-->
                                <hr>
                                <!-- /.box-header -->
                                <div class="box-body">
                                    <div class="col-xs-7">
                                        <table id="table_plaza"
                                               class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover responsive"
                                               cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th><FONT SIZE=4>Código</FONT></th>
                                                    <th width="320px"><FONT SIZE=4>Producto</FONT></th>
                                                    <th><FONT SIZE=4>Precio</FONT></th>
                                                    <th><FONT SIZE=4>Cantidad</FONT></th>
                                                    <th><FONT SIZE=4>Subtotal</FONT></th>
                                                    <th width="5%"></th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tfoot>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td></th>
                                                    <td></th>
                                                    <td></th>
                                                    <td style="text-align: right;"><strong><FONT SIZE=4>TOTAL</FONT></strong></th>
                                                    <td id="detalle_total">0<th> 
                                                </tr>
                                            </tfoot>
                                            <tbody>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div align="center" id="modal_footer">
                                                <div align="center">
                                                    <button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="guardar_plaza()"
                                                            class="btn btn-danger btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i> CANCELAR COMPRA</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-5" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;">
                                        <div class="box-body">
                                            <div class="form-vertical">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-xs-12" align="center">
                                                        <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
                                                            <div class="form-group" align="center">
                                                                <label  class="control-label col-md-12"><FONT SIZE=6>BUSQUEDA DE PRODUCTO</FONT></label>                                                           
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>                                                    
                                                    </div><br>
                                                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label class="control-label col-md-4">Producto</label>
                                                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                                                    <select class="form-control select2" id="producto" name="Ingrese el nombre del Producto"
                                                                            style="width: 100%"></select> <span class="help-block"></span>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label class="control-label col-md-4">Precio</label>
                                                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                                                    <input id="precio"
                                                                           placeholder="0"
                                                                           class="form-control" type="text"> <span class="help-block"></span>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label class="control-label col-md-4">Cantidad</label>
                                                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                                                    <input id="cantidad_stock"
                                                                           placeholder="0"
                                                                           class="form-control" type="text"> <span class="help-block"></span>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div><br>
                                                <div class="row" align="center">
                                                    <div class="col-xs-12" align="center">
                                                        <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
                                                            <div class="form-group" align="center">
                                                                <label  class="control-label col-md-12">Cantidad a Comprar</label>
                                                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                                                    <input id="cantidad_comprar"
                                                                           placeholder="0"
                                                                           class="form-control" type="text"> <span class="help-block"></span>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>                                                    
                                                    </div>
                                                </div><br>
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-xs-12" align="center">
                                                        <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
                                                            <div class="form-group" align="center">
                                                                <label  class="control-label col-md-12"><FONT SIZE=6>CLIENTE</FONT></label>                                                           
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>                                                    
                                                    </div><br>
                                                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label class="control-label col-md-4">DNI</label>
                                                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                                                    <select class="form-control select2" id="DNI" name="Ingrese el DNI"
                                                                            style="width: 100%"></select> <span class="help-block"></span>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label class="control-label col-md-4">Nombres</label>
                                                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                                                    <input id="nombres"
                                                                           placeholder="Nombres"
                                                                           class="form-control" type="text"> <span class="help-block"></span>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div><br>
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-xs-12" align="center">
                                                        <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
                                                            <div class="form-group" align="center">
                                                                <label  class="control-label col-md-12"><FONT SIZE=6>DESCUENTO - EFECTIVO</FONT></label>                                                           
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>                                                    
                                                    </div><br>
                                                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label class="control-label col-md-4">Descuento</label>
                                                                <input id="descuento"
                                                                           placeholder="0"
                                                                           class="form-control" type="text"> <span class="help-block"></span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label class="control-label col-md-4">Efectivo</label>
                                                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                                                    <input id="efectivo"
                                                                           placeholder="0"
                                                                           class="form-control" type="text"> <span class="help-block"></span>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div><br>
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div align="center" id="modal_footer">
                                                        <button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="guardar_plaza()"
                                                                class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Agregar</button>
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal"> <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Limpiar</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <br>
                                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                                    <div align="center">
                                                        <button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="guardar_plaza()"
                                                                class="btn btn-success btn-lg"><i class="fa  fa-check"></i> CONFIRMAR COMPRA</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div><br>
                                            </div>                    
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
    
                    </div>
                </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo que puedes hacer es usar FlexBox. De ese modo podrías hacer que la columna de la izquierda tenga la misma altura que la columna de la derecha (que parece ser más grande), y a partir de ahí usar posicionamiento para que el botón aparezca abajo del todo (que es donde aparece el botón de "Confirmar venta").

Lo que podrías hacer es:

- Añadir un ID al contenedor para que sea más fácil identificarlo y aplcicarle estilos.
- Ponerle `display:flex` al contenedor (automáticamente por los estilos que tienen, las columnas pasarán a ocupar la misma altura) y `position:relative` (para que los elementos posicionados sean relativos al contenedor).
- Cambiar el posicionamiento del botón (`#modal_footer`) para que se coloque en el centro y abajo del contenedor.

Algo como esto:

```css
#pagina-venta {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

/* El código tiene ID's repetidos, por eso hay que ser más específicos */
#pagina-venta > div:nth-child(1) #modal_footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<section class="content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="box box-solid box-primary">
        <div class="box-header">
          <h3 class="box-title">
            <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Venta
          </h3>
        </div>
        <!--<br>-->
        <hr>
        <!-- /.box-header -->
        <div class="box-body" id="pagina-venta">
          <div class="col-xs-7">
            <table id="table_plaza" class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover responsive" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>
                    <FONT SIZE=4>Código</FONT>
                  </th>
                  <th width="320px">
                    <FONT SIZE=4>Producto</FONT>
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    <FONT SIZE=4>Precio</FONT>
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    <FONT SIZE=4>Cantidad</FONT>
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    <FONT SIZE=4>Subtotal</FONT>
                  </th>
                  <th width="5%"></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tfoot>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    </th>
                    <td>
                      </th>
                      <td>
                        </th>
                        <td style="text-align: right;"><strong><FONT SIZE=4>TOTAL</FONT></strong></th>
                          <td id="detalle_total">0
                            <th>
                </tr>
              </tfoot>
              <tbody>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="row">
              <div align="center" id="modal_footer">
                <div align="center">
                  <button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="guardar_plaza()" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i> CANCELAR COMPRA</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-5" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;">
            <div class="box-body">
              <div class="form-vertical">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-12" align="center">
                    <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
                      <div class="form-group" align="center">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-12"><FONT SIZE=6>BUSQUEDA DE PRODUCTO</FONT></label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div><br>
                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-4">Producto</label>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          <select class="form-control select2" id="producto" name="Ingrese el nombre del Producto" style="width: 100%"></select> <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-4">Precio</label>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          <input id="precio" placeholder="0" class="form-control" type="text"> <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-4">Cantidad</label>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          <input id="cantidad_stock" placeholder="0" class="form-control" type="text"> <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div><br>
                <div class="row" align="center">
                  <div class="col-xs-12" align="center">
                    <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
                      <div class="form-group" align="center">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-12">Cantidad a Comprar</label>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          <input id="cantidad_comprar" placeholder="0" class="form-control" type="text"> <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div><br>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-12" align="center">
                    <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
                      <div class="form-group" align="center">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-12"><FONT SIZE=6>CLIENTE</FONT></label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div><br>
                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-4">DNI</label>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          <select class="form-control select2" id="DNI" name="Ingrese el DNI" style="width: 100%"></select> <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-4">Nombres</label>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          <input id="nombres" placeholder="Nombres" class="form-control" type="text"> <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div><br>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-12" align="center">
                    <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
                      <div class="form-group" align="center">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-12"><FONT SIZE=6>DESCUENTO - EFECTIVO</FONT></label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div><br>
                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-4">Descuento</label>
                        <input id="descuento" placeholder="0" class="form-control" type="text"> <span class="help-block"></span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-4">Efectivo</label>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          <input id="efectivo" placeholder="0" class="form-control" type="text"> <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div><br>
                <div class="row">
                  <div align="center" id="modal_footer">
                    <button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="guardar_plaza()" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Agregar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal"> <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Limpiar</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                  <div align="center">
                    <button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="guardar_plaza()" class="btn btn-success btn-lg"><i class="fa  fa-check"></i> CONFIRMAR COMPRA</button>
                  </div>
                </div><br>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

---

Otra opción si lo que quieres es bajar todo el contenido de la parte izquierda, sería añadir un nuevo elemento arriba y ponerle `flex:1`. De ese modo ocupará el alto máximo posible y ya no necesitarás usar el posicionamiento absoluto para la tabla o el botón.

Entonces la tabla irá creciendo hacia arriba en lugar de hacia abajo y tabla y botón estarán alineadas en la parte baja del contenedor.

Algo como esto:

```css
#pagina-venta {
  display: flex;
}

#pagina-venta>div:nth-child(1) {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#separador {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<section class="content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="box box-solid box-primary">
        <div class="box-header">
          <h3 class="box-title">
            <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Venta
          </h3>
        </div>
        <!--<br>-->
        <hr>
        <!-- /.box-header -->
        <div class="box-body" id="pagina-venta">
          <div class="col-xs-7">
            <div id="separador"></div>
            <table id="table_plaza" class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover responsive" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>
                    <FONT SIZE=4>Código</FONT>
                  </th>
                  <th width="320px">
                    <FONT SIZE=4>Producto</FONT>
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    <FONT SIZE=4>Precio</FONT>
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    <FONT SIZE=4>Cantidad</FONT>
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    <FONT SIZE=4>Subtotal</FONT>
                  </th>
                  <th width="5%"></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tfoot>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    </th>
                    <td>
                      </th>
                      <td>
                        </th>
                        <td style="text-align: right;"><strong><FONT SIZE=4>TOTAL</FONT></strong></th>
                          <td id="detalle_total">0
                            <th>
                </tr>
              </tfoot>
              <tbody>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="row">
              <div align="center" id="modal_footer">
                <div align="center">
                  <button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="guardar_plaza()" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i> CANCELAR COMPRA</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-5" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;">
            <div class="box-body">
              <div class="form-vertical">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-12" align="center">
                    <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
                      <div class="form-group" align="center">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-12"><FONT SIZE=6>BUSQUEDA DE PRODUCTO</FONT></label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div><br>
                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-4">Producto</label>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          <select class="form-control select2" id="producto" name="Ingrese el nombre del Producto" style="width: 100%"></select> <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-4">Precio</label>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          <input id="precio" placeholder="0" class="form-control" type="text"> <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-4">Cantidad</label>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          <input id="cantidad_stock" placeholder="0" class="form-control" type="text"> <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div><br>
                <div class="row" align="center">
                  <div class="col-xs-12" align="center">
                    <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
                      <div class="form-group" align="center">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-12">Cantidad a Comprar</label>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          <input id="cantidad_comprar" placeholder="0" class="form-control" type="text"> <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div><br>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-12" align="center">
                    <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
                      <div class="form-group" align="center">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-12"><FONT SIZE=6>CLIENTE</FONT></label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div><br>
                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-4">DNI</label>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          <select class="form-control select2" id="DNI" name="Ingrese el DNI" style="width: 100%"></select> <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-4">Nombres</label>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          <input id="nombres" placeholder="Nombres" class="form-control" type="text"> <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div><br>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-12" align="center">
                    <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
                      <div class="form-group" align="center">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-12"><FONT SIZE=6>DESCUENTO - EFECTIVO</FONT></label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div><br>
                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-4">Descuento</label>
                        <input id="descuento" placeholder="0" class="form-control" type="text"> <span class="help-block"></span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-4">Efectivo</label>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          <input id="efectivo" placeholder="0" class="form-control" type="text"> <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div><br>
                <div class="row">
                  <div align="center" id="modal_footer">
                    <button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="guardar_plaza()" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Agregar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal"> <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Limpiar</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                  <div align="center">
                    <button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="guardar_plaza()" class="btn btn-success btn-lg"><i class="fa  fa-check"></i> CONFIRMAR COMPRA</button>
                  </div>
                </div><br>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Una ultima pregunta como seria para bajar el total, sera poniendo el tamaño fijo de la tabla o tendria que hacer algo igual, por favor responde

Comment: @IvanMoreFlores He añadido un ejemplo de una manera de hacerlo. Quizás no sea la mejor, pero es simple y funciona

Comment: Pero eso baja todo? yo quiero que solo el label TOTAL  que esta en fotter de la table baje solo eso no todos.

Comment: Oh ok. Ahora estoy de camino a casa. Lo miro cuando llegue

Comment: Espero tu aydua gracias

Comment: Estoy haciendo pruebas, pero no se me ocurre nada que no sea "hacky" para poner la última fila abajo. Si encuentro algo actualizo la respuesta, pero no sé si va a ser posible mover sólo el `tfoot`

Comment: asu pero si le damos tamaño a la tabla?

Comment: aun nada :c sigo intendado

Answer (score 0):

Crea un nuevo row con los dos juntos es la forma

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<section class="content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="box box-solid box-primary">
        <div class="box-header">
          <h3 class="box-title">
            <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Venta
          </h3>
        </div>
        <!--<br>-->
        <hr>
        <!-- /.box-header -->
        <div class="box-body">
          <div class="col-xs-7">
            <table id="table_plaza"
            class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover responsive"
            cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th><FONT SIZE=4>Código</FONT></th>
                <th width="320px"><FONT SIZE=4>Producto</FONT></th>
                <th><FONT SIZE=4>Precio</FONT></th>
                <th><FONT SIZE=4>Cantidad</FONT></th>
                <th><FONT SIZE=4>Subtotal</FONT></th>
                <th width="5%"></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
              <tr>
                <td></th>
                  <td></th>
                    <td></th>
                      <td style="text-align: right;"><strong><FONT SIZE=4>TOTAL</FONT></strong></th>
                        <td id="detalle_total">0<th>
                        </tr>
                      </tfoot>
                      <tbody>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-5" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;">
                    <div class="box-body">
                      <div class="form-vertical">
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-xs-12" align="center">
                            <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
                              <div class="form-group" align="center">
                                <label  class="control-label col-md-12"><FONT SIZE=6>BUSQUEDA DE PRODUCTO</FONT></label>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div><br>
                          <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-md-4">Producto</label>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                  <select class="form-control select2" id="producto" name="Ingrese el nombre del Producto"
                                  style="width: 100%"></select> <span class="help-block"></span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-md-4">Precio</label>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                  <input id="precio"
                                  placeholder="0"
                                  class="form-control" type="text"> <span class="help-block"></span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-md-4">Cantidad</label>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                  <input id="cantidad_stock"
                                  placeholder="0"
                                  class="form-control" type="text"> <span class="help-block"></span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div><br>
                        <div class="row" align="center">
                          <div class="col-xs-12" align="center">
                            <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
                              <div class="form-group" align="center">
                                <label  class="control-label col-md-12">Cantidad a Comprar</label>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                  <input id="cantidad_comprar"
                                  placeholder="0"
                                  class="form-control" type="text"> <span class="help-block"></span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div><br>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-xs-12" align="center">
                            <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
                              <div class="form-group" align="center">
                                <label  class="control-label col-md-12"><FONT SIZE=6>CLIENTE</FONT></label>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div><br>
                          <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-md-4">DNI</label>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                  <select class="form-control select2" id="DNI" name="Ingrese el DNI"
                                  style="width: 100%"></select> <span class="help-block"></span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-md-4">Nombres</label>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                  <input id="nombres"
                                  placeholder="Nombres"
                                  class="form-control" type="text"> <span class="help-block"></span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div><br>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-xs-12" align="center">
                            <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
                              <div class="form-group" align="center">
                                <label  class="control-label col-md-12"><FONT SIZE=6>DESCUENTO - EFECTIVO</FONT></label>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div><br>
                          <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-md-4">Descuento</label>
                                <input id="descuento"
                                placeholder="0"
                                class="form-control" type="text"> <span class="help-block"></span>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-md-4">Efectivo</label>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                  <input id="efectivo"
                                  placeholder="0"
                                  class="form-control" type="text"> <span class="help-block"></span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div><br>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div align="center" id="modal_footer">
                            <button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="guardar_plaza()"
                            class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Agregar</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal"> <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Limpiar</button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <div align="center">
                <button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="guardar_plaza()"
                class="btn btn-success btn-lg"><i class="fa  fa-check"></i> CONFIRMAR COMPRA</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <div align="center" id="modal_footer">
                <div align="center">
                  <button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="guardar_plaza()"
                  class="btn btn-danger btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i> CANCELAR COMPRA</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero teniendo encuenta que tambien tengo que bajar el label Total, esto se complicaria ya que la respuesta solo es para el boton